# Sorting Problem using Custom Entity Databinding

Tags: c#, sorting, entity

I have problem sorting my Gridview using my custom entity classes

My complex entity

```
public class Subscription
{

    public string SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Customer { get; set; } //Contained class from another entity
}


public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Binding to gridview

```
 List<Subscription> subscriptions = GetSubscriptions();


 //sorting, sortEvent is the GridviewSortEvenArgs param
 subscriptions.Sort(new GenericComparer<Subscription>(sortEvent.SortExpression, GridViewSortDirection));



 grdSubscription.DataSource = subscriptions;
 grdSubscription.DataBind();
```

I use template field to bind my entity fields into the grid

```
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subscription ID" SortExpression="SubscriptionID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <%# Eval(" SubscriptionID ") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="CustomerName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <%# Eval(" Customer.CustomerName ") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now in sorting, its works fine when sorting Subscription's Native property

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subscription ID" SortExpression="SubscriptionID">
```

But I'm having problem in sorting properties of the contained class (Customer)

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="CustomerName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval(" Customer.CustomerName ") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

I tried  SortExpression="Customer.CustomerName"  but to no avail

I used this GenericComparer in sorting the grid

```
   public class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private SortDirection sortDirection;

    public SortDirection SortDirection
    {
        get { return this.sortDirection; }
        set { this.sortDirection = value; }

    }

    private string sortExpression;

    public GenericComparer(string sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        this.sortExpression = sortExpression;
        this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortExpression);

        IComparable obj1 = (IComparable)propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
        IComparable obj2 = (IComparable)propertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);

        if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            return obj1.CompareTo(obj2);
        }

        else return obj2.CompareTo(obj1);
    }
}
```

additional details:

```
     protected SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        // Checks for the first time when the ViewState sort direction is null
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        // Changes the sort direction
        else
        {
            if (((SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"]) == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortDirection"] = value;

    }
}
```

Please advise, thanks in advance

Comment: How are you binding the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick-and-dirty thing you could try is to add a CustomerName property to your Subscription class. I usually do this in a client-side code partial class when using Silverlight/WCF/EF.

```
public string CustomerName 
{ get 
   { return Customer != null ? Customer.CustomerName : string.empty }
}
```

Then reference this property from your UI.

Comment: Yeah i can simply add this but it will be promoting redunduncy since I already have the CustomerName on my Customer Class... I designed my entities as the normalized table of my actual database.. thanks

Comment: I use this when I want to eliminate the question "where is my data problem". For example, in EF sometimes the Subscription objects are not deep-loaded (e.g., the Customer instance is not created unless .Include("Customer") is in the query method). After you resolve those issues, you can remove the "redundant" property (although users of your Subscription class may appreciate the helper method vs. always having to code "subscription.Customer.CustomerName")